# Добавить поле в таблицу БД (Yii2)

Tags: mysql, yii2

Как безопасно добавить поле в таблицу в БД на сайте, который на Yii2? Просто добавить поле запросом к БД и добавить это поле в модель или что-то еще нужно сделать? Строки в таблице есть, а поле может быть пустым. Очень важно сделать безопасно и без косяков, так как записей в таблице много и сайт крутится на проде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понятное дело что таблица заблокируется и есть два варианта

1. Просто забиваешь  и делаешь альтер/миграцию
2. гуглим percona online schema change

Comment: По этой инструкции можно просто? https://treecode.ru/article/10/yii2_migration_alter_column_and_drop_column

Comment: Да.По идеи должно все отработать.Но я говорил об последствиях миграции, если данных реально много в таблице :)

Comment: А как тогда лучше поступить если данных там много? Использовать второй пункт, который вы предложили? Или создать дополнительную таблицу?

Comment: Сколько записей в таблице ? count(*) Может у нас разные понимания что такое много

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/121129/

Comment: Записей в таблице - 81736

Comment: Если таблица заблокируется на час, то ничего страшного, сделаем просто ночью изменение. Или может быть больше?

Comment: Смотри сейчас будет плохой совет :) данных не много по сути. Можешь на тестовое бд прогнать и глянуть скок таблица будет заблокирована. И выбрать момент когда будет меньше всего активности и сделать альтер :)

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение) А вот еще вопрос не по теме - я не могу найти в проекте папки миграций, их могли не делать в проекте? Если да, то как расширяли таблицы? Просто это точно было сделано пару раз.

Comment: хм, возможно их не закомитили . Глянь в базе есть ли такая таблица $$_migration эта таблица создаеться средставими yii2, сюда пишуться когда применялись миграции

Comment: Неа, нет, у меня доступ к проду. Там даже php yii migrate пишет что нет папки миграций. Возможно, ли что делали просто sql + изменяли модель каждый раз? Сам проект делали очень на костылях, прям очень.

Comment: Скорее всего так